# Adding an application firewall rule to both private and public networks via win7 FirewallAPI

Tags: c#, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api, firewall-access

A little background: Basicaly I'd like to add a program firewall access rule to both private and public networks.

I used to use this-
"netsh firewall add allowedprogram program= "Path.." name=AppName ENABLE scope=ALL profile=CURRENT"

But now I'd like to automate the proccess a little using a COM object.
Found this shiny piece of code - http://web.archive.org/web/20070707110141/http://www.dot.net.nz/Default.aspx?tabid=42&mid=404&ctl=Details&ItemID=8

And after implementing the class I've been trying to use-
FirewallHelper.Instance.GrantAuthorization(@"Path... ","AppName ",NET_FW_SCOPE_.NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL,NET_FW_IP_VERSION_.NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY);

The problem I'm facing is that the GrantAuthorization method will only add a rule for the public OR private network whereas my old netsh command would 2 rules for- 1 for each network.

The commands actually seems very similar so it is kinda buffling to me.

So... how to add both network rules?

Shaun

Answer (score 17):

My answer is from David's answer but more detail. And fix problem about setting Localports. You need to setting Protocol before setting Localports. More detail is bellow:

the first, you need to import reference FirewallAPI.dll. It's in "C:\Windows\System32\FirewallAPI.dll"
then:

```
using NetFwTypeLib;
```

and insert code into your:

```
        Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
        INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
        var currentProfiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;

        // Let's create a new rule
        INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
        inboundRule.Enabled = true;
        //Allow through firewall
        inboundRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
        //Using protocol TCP
        inboundRule.Protocol = 6; // TCP
        //Port 81
        inboundRule.LocalPorts = "81";
        //Name of rule
        inboundRule.Name = "MyRule";
        // ...//
        inboundRule.Profiles = currentProfiles;

        // Now add the rule
        INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
        firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
```

Answer (score 9):

I think your best bet is to talk to the [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A quick google for "C# INetFwRule2" will show you numerous examples of how to register or update a Firewall rule.

In order to add to both public and private policies i've used something along the lines of

```
Type tNetFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(tNetFwPolicy2);
var currentProfiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;

// Let's create a new rule

INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
inboundRule.Enabled = true;
inboundRule.LocalPorts = "1234";
inboundRule.Protocol = 6; // TCP
// ...
inboundRule.Profiles = currentProfiles;

// Now add the rule

INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
```

Answer (score 7):

This page doesn't say this has been answered and is old, so just in case, for future use, I'll answer this.

First, import reference FirewallAPI.dll, located at "C:\Windows\System32\FirewallAPI.dll", then add the using directive

```
using NetFwTypeLib;
```

The `inboundRule.Profiles` property seems to be classified as a set of flags with the following values (the property's type is an int, so i made an enum):

```
public enum FirewallProfiles
{
    Domain = 1,
    Private = 2,
    Public = 4
}
```

So, with that code, we can change the Profiles to the following:

```
// Create a new rule
INetFwRule2 inboundRule = (INetFwRule2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwRule"));
// Enable the rule
inboundRule.Enabled = true;
// Allow through firewall
inboundRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
// Using protocol TCP
inboundRule.Protocol = 6; // TCP
// Set port number
inboundRule.LocalPorts = "1234";
// Name of rule
inboundRule.Name = "Name Of Firewall Rule";
// Set profiles
inboundRule.Profiles = (int)(FirewallProfiles.Private | FirewallProfiles.Public);

// Add the rule
INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
```

Or you could change `inboundRule.Profiles` to an int value.

Two notes:

1: If you don't run this code under administrative privilege's,

```
firewallPolicty.Rules.Add(inboundRule);
```

will throw an exception.

2: `inboundRule.Profiles` must be between values 1 and 7.  Otherwise, it will throw an exception

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you guys want **Outbound** rule:

```
inboundRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `netsh` commands using a standard `Process` to run `cmd.exe`. The `netsh` command first checks for the existence of the firewall rule and if it doesn't exist it creates it, otherwise it's updated.

I choose to avoid deleting the rule because this would interrupt connected services when verifying the rule.

```
static void SetFirewallException(string ruleName, string exePath)
{

    string script = $@"netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=""{ruleName}"" > nul & if errorlevel 1 (netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""{ruleName}"" dir=in action=allow program=""{exePath}"" enable=yes) else (netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=""{ruleName}"" new program=""{exePath}"")";

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + script;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```