# C# - Windows server 2016 firewall - skip the confirmation screen

Tags: c#, firewall

I'm adding new remote ip to the Windows server 2016 firewall with C # programming. But I want to skip the confirmation screen. Because this is a web application. Is there a way?

Comment: Did you try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409790/adding-an-application-firewall-rule-to-both-private-and-public-networks-via-win7)?

Comment: Yes, i using it(NetFwTypeLib). it is working. But, i want to skip the confirmation message.

Comment: And what about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps) article? I've tried using this command in PowerShell, added a rule to my firewall and the operation was successful, but you have to run it as an administrator I assume. It didn't trigger the confirmation message, though you can add `-Confirm` to the command, to trigger the confirmation.

Comment: The link was the solution for me [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581142/why-is-this-process-crashing-as-soon-as-it-is-launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581142/why-is-this-process-crashing-as-soon-as-it-is-launched)